# Custom MVC Framework: How set links in view files

Tags: php, model-view-controller, seo, url-routing

I'm creating a custom MVC framework, but I'm stuck with some URL definitions in the view files. I have this piece of code which lets me use SEO friendly links:

```
$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptName = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($scriptName); $i++) 
{
    if( $requestURI[$i] == $scriptName[$i]) 
    {
        unset($requestURI[$i]);
    }
}

$command = array_values($requestURI);

if( sizeof($command) === 0 OR sizeof($command) === 1)
{
    init_controller_class($config['default_controller'], $config['default_entry']);
}
elseif( sizeof($command) >= 2)
{
    init_controller_class($command[0], $command[1]);
}
```

My view file:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="header">
          <ul class="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About µMVC</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

The URL for the landing page is http://mvc.localhost:8888/welcome/index. How do I set the URLs in this menu?
Because, if I insert `<li><a href="welcome/about">About µMVC</a></li>`, it will redirect to http://mvc.localhost:8888/welcome/welcome/about and obviously my script will terminate, 'cause function `welcome` with parameter value `'about'` does not exist in the controller `welcome`. How to eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use absolute paths in your links, like /welcome/about

Comment: I've resolved 6 minutes ago, it was only an error in the script that let me use the SEO Urls